# Ubuntu 23.10 stuck in airplane mode

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, usb

I have created a dual boot USB drive for my Dell laptop running Windows 10. I am running Ubuntu directly from the USB installer in live (try) mode before I install it.

The Ubuntu distro is stuck in airplane mode and I can not access the Wi-Fi or connected LAN though the ethernet cable. When I go to settings and try to turn on the Wi-Fi with the slider button, it automatically slide back and remains off (greyed out).

Can anyone suggest a fix for this issue?

Attached is the terminal output to @jeremy31 comment

[Bios Setting For Dell Latitude E6430](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acpyd.png)

Comment: What Dell laptop are you using? There’s usually a bios setting to enable / disable airplane mode, eg using a function key or (occasionally) a physical switch on the chassis.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `rfkill list; sudo cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state; lsmod | egrep -i 'wmi|dell'`

Comment: Thank you @jeremy31. The laptop model is Dell Latitude E6430. The results of the terminal command you suggested is appended to the question.

Comment: Try the FN function key combo to see if that will enable wifi

Comment: Thank you Jeremy31...that was the problem...easy peasy...